# What is PostgreSQL equivalent for MSSQL EXEC @return_value = procedurename @par1, @par2= @result OUTPUT?

Tags: postgresql

What is PostgreSQL equivalent for MSSQL

```
EXEC @return_value = procedurename @par1, @par2= @result
```

OUTPUT? Does anyone know is there such an equivalent in Postgres for `@return_value`?

Comment: Please explain what that T-SQL code is doing. You can't expect that people knowing Postgres know SQL Server's T-SQL as well. But in general, if you want to return something, you use a function: `return_value := some_function(par1, par2)`

Comment: In default, when we execute a stored procedure in MSSQL Server, it returns an integer value and this value indicates the execution status of the stored procedure. The 0 value indicates, the procedure is completed successfully and the non-zero values indicate an error.

Comment: There is no built in Postgres equivalent. You can build that into procedures (making them functions). In Postgres the basic process generally is: *If successful just return; If error raise exception.*